# D3 line chart legend not working with v3 but working with v2

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Please check below URL for code example. This works well with d3 2.x but not with d3 3.2.2: while clicking on the legends I am getting some error in console.

Working copy with v2: http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070123

Not working with v3.x: http://jsfiddle.net/lalits2002/Q5Jag/3328/

These are the scripts in v2 version:

```
<script src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="nvtooltip.js"></script>
<script src="d3legend.js"></script> 
<script src="d3line.js"></script> 
<script src="d3linewithlegend.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exact reason but It seems like something related to transition has been changed. I made following change and it is working. Check out updated revision of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/3342/)

```
 legend.dispatch.on('legendClick', function(d, i) { 
     // existing code

     // Added this to render chart again.
     d3.select('#test1 svg').transition(selection).call(chart);
     // Removed following code 
     // selection.transition().call(chart)
 });

 // similar error in legendMouseout and legendMouseover so removed both currently.

 // legend.dispatch.on('legendMouseover', function(d, i) {
 //   d.hover = true;
 //   selection.transition().call(chart)
 // });

 // legend.dispatch.on('legendMouseout', function(d, i) {
 //  d.hover = false;
 //   selection.transition().call(chart)
 // });
```

Comment: Now I am facing issue while rendering chart. Everything is same but when I am using bit different data its not working. Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lalits2002/Q5Jag/3386/  Non-Working: https://jsfiddle.net/lalits2002/m90ctxsn/   could you please check for the issue?